# Insert empty int array into a hive table

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, hiveql

let's say I have a hive table that has only one column of type `array<int>`.

I can insert into that table by

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablename SELECT array(1);
```

but what if I want to insert an empty int array into that column? Didn't figure out. Tried with `array()`, `[]`, `array<int>` and `array<int>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me

```
collect_set(CAST(NULL AS INT))
```